# how to use below response received from server and save in to database

Tags: java, android, http

i send contacts to sever to check whether it is registered on server or not and server returns this response how to use it and save into database  number and according to number result true and false
7837580550,false,9780929022,true,9855772008,false,

Comment: what request you are sending and what response you are getting?? post it too.

Comment: elaborate more.. its not enough to understand ?

Comment: i think i already mentioned the response received from server but any way this is response 7837580550,false,9780929022,true,9855772008,false, received from server

Comment: split response into an array get values from array             String[] arr=response.split(",");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a List of Map to the store the values and insert into database using it.

```
String[] arr=response.split(",");
List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i+2){
String contactNo = arr[i];
String result = arr[i+1];
Map<String,String> m = new HashMap();
m.put(contactNo,result);
list.add(m);
}
```

Comment: are you getting the response in a comma separated string ?

Comment: yes this is response received from server 7837580550,false,9780929022,true,9855772008,false,

Comment: edited the code.. you can use this list to insert according to the db you are using

Comment: Map m<String,String> = new HashMap();                                 getting error on thid line Syntax error on this tokens,Expression expected instead

Comment: sorry.. my mistake one > missed

Comment: i know but use like this Map<String,String>  m = new HashMap(); instead of Map m<String,String> = new HashMap();

Answer (score 0):

As per my thinking you should get response in XMl format. I will be easy to handle and easy to manage the parsed output.

```
<Response>
  <MobileNo>7837580550</MobileNo>
  <Status>False</Status>
  <MobileNo>9780929022</MobileNo>
  <Status>True</Status>
  <MobileNo>9855772008</MobileNo>
  <Status>False</Status>
</Response>
```

While parsing you can store parsed information in different array. Rest you know how to get data from array and store in db.

Hope this will help.